# Schwarz-Pick type inequality for $f:\mathbb{D}\to D(0,R)$ holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{D}\to D(0,R)$ be a holomorphic function and let $a_i\in \mathbb{D}, 1\leq i\leq n$ such that $f(a_i)=0$ for every $i$. Show that $$|f(z)|\leq R\prod_{i=1}^n \left|\dfrac{a_i-z}{1-\overline{a_i}z}\right| $$for every $z\in\mathbb{D}$.

So obviously, defining $g(z)=f(z)/R:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ and using the Schwarz-Pick lemma gives you the inequality in the special case $n=1$, but I was having trouble generalizing this to the case of arbitrary $n$. You can still do this type of construction for arbitrary $n$, and get that $|f(z)|\leq R\left|\dfrac{a_i-z}{1-\overline{a_i}z}\right| $ for every $i$, but I'm having difficulty from going to this introductory step to the general case.

Ideas?

Comment: Are these all the zeros of $f,$ and are they counted according to multiplicity?

Comment: The question didn't say if I'm remembering correctly. This was a problem from my complex analysis final a few days ago so this is mostly from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $f:\mathbb {D} \to \mathbb {D}$ is analytic and has the zeros in your statement. Consider

$$(1)\,\,\,\,\frac{f(z)}{\prod_{i=1}^n g_i},$$

where $g_i$ is the Blaschke factor you mentioned. This function is analytic in $\mathbb {D}.$ So if you can show it still maps into $\mathbb {D},$ it will answer your question.

Comment: To make sense of this, you would need absolute values on that product. But no, that product blows up at each $a_i,$ so how could its absolute value be bounded?